# Is there a way to add EventHandler to the close window button (the X on title bar) JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

As in the title - I've been looking for this for some time, and I don't seem to find the answer. Neither setOnHiding nor setOnHidden stage methods works with the close X-button.

EDIT: What I wanted to achive is to reset the value of a variable on the close action. This is easily done with a custom controller - MenuItem in this case (setOnHidden worked here, but not setOnCloseRequest). The latter method worked with the close button, as suggested in the answers.

Comment: [`Window#onCloseRequest`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Window.html#onCloseRequestProperty)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use EventHandler to catch `WindowEvent`

```
public class MYUI extends Application implements EventHandler<WindowEvent> {  
    @Override  
    public void start(Stage s) throws Exception {  
      s.setOnCloseRequest(this);  
    }  

    @Override  
    public void stop() throws Exception {  
    }  

    @Override  
    public void handle(WindowEvent event) {  
        [...] your code
    }  
}
```

or as MadProgrammer suggested

```
stage.setOnCloseRequest(new EventHandler<WindowEvent>() {

      @Override
      public void handle(WindowEvent we) {
          [...] // your code
      }

});
```

Comment: Many thanks for the answer! To achive what I've been trying I had to combine both setOnCloseRequest and setOnHidden methods. Your and @MadProgrammers answers lead me to the solution. I would vote both your answers if only I could! Thank you!